# Equivalence of two definitions of polar of polytope

Tags: linear-algebra, convex-analysis, convex-optimization, linear-programming, polyhedra

Let $a_i \in \mathbb{R}^n$. $P = \{ x_i \vert \  a_i \cdot x_i \leq 1 \ \forall x_i \in \mathbb{R}^n, i \in [1\dots n] \}$, **P is bounded**. Since P is a bounded polyhedra, it is a polytope (by Weyl-Minkowski).

Now, consider:

$$
\begin{align}
Q_1 &= \text{Conv}(a_1, a_2, \dots, a_n) \\
Q_2 &= \{ y  \mid  y \cdot p \leq 1, \forall y \in \mathbb{R}^n, \forall p \in P \}
\end{align}
$$

Prove that $Q_1 = Q_2$. We know that $Q_2$ is the standard definiton of polar. We wish to show equivalence to the first form. Roughly, we wish to show that the polar of a polytope is a polytope, with the new vertices being the hyperplane normals. Note that we are using a *normalized* polytope, with the constraints $\leq 1$.

### Forward direction of proof ($Q_1 \subseteq Q_2$)

The rough sketch is as follows. Let $q \in Q_1$. Since $Q_1$ is the convex hull of $a_1, \dots, a_n$:

$$
q = \sum_i a_i \lambda_i \\
$$

Where $\lambda_i$ are of the form:
$$
\begin{align}
\lambda_i &\in \mathbb{R} \\
\lambda_i &\geq 0 \\
\sum_i \lambda_i &= 1
\end{align}
$$

$\forall p \in P$, consider $q \cdot p$.

$
q \cdot p =
(\sum_i a_i \lambda_i) \cdot p =
\sum (a_i \cdot p) \lambda_i
$

Each $a_i \cdot p \leq 1$, because $p \in P$, hence by definition of $P$ the inequality holds.

Therefore, $\sum (a_i \cdot p) \lambda_i \leq \sum 1 \lambda_i \leq \sum \lambda_i$.

We know that $\sum \lambda_i = 1$ by definition.
Hence, $\forall p \in P, q \cdot p \leq \sum \lambda_i \leq 1$.

Hence, $q \in Q_2$, and $Q_1 \subseteq Q_2$.

### Backward Direction of Proof ($Q_2 \subseteq Q_1$)

I have gotten stuck when trying to prove this. The obstacle I face is this: given some point $q \in Q_2$, we need to actually *describe* such a point as a convex combination of $a_i$. I have no idea how to come up with the $\lambda_i$ coefficients.

Any proof strategy hints would be very welcome :)

Comment: Your definition of $P$ does not make sense due to the $\forall x_i$. Do you mean $P = \{ x \in \mathbb{R}^n : a_i \cdot x \leq 1 \forall i \in \{1,..,n\} \}$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following *incomplete* proof uses LP duality.
$$\begin{align}
Q_2 &= \{ y \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid y \cdot p \leq 1 \; \forall p : a_i \cdot p \leq 1 \} \\
&= \{ y \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid \max_p \{ y \cdot p \mid a_i \cdot p \leq 1 \} \leq 1 \} \\
&= \{ y \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid \min_{\lambda \in \mathbb{R}^n_+} \{ \sum \lambda_i \mid \sum_i \lambda_i a_i = y \} \leq 1 \} \\
&= \{ y \in \mathbb{R}^n \mid \exists \lambda \in \mathbb{R}^n_+ : \sum_i \lambda_i \leq 1, \sum_i \lambda_i a_i = y \}
\end{align}$$
This is almost correct, the only problem being the sum of $\lambda$ is not necessarily $1$. We have not used that $P$ is *bounded*.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer. I'm actually unsure how you would control $\lambda_i$ using the fact that $P$ is bounded. May I have a hint or a full proof? I've never seen duality used within algebraic manipulation before :)

Comment: It has to do with $0 \in Q_i$, and giving it weight $1-\sum_i \lambda_i$.